# Backup / Restore Notepad++ themes

Tags: html, css

So, I've created my own colors on a theme in Notepad++ on HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT etc.. (DarkModeDefault).

I wonder, is it possible to backup the whole theme on the desktop and after restore it, because I have done a lot of work and I do not want to lose all the color settings if I format the pc...

Thank you very much

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983048/where-does-notepad-store-style-configurator-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest backup method is to copy the folder `%appdata%\notepad++`.

This folder contains everything that you have set or changed in Notepad++,
including installed themes or any other settings such as color.

You may also use this folder when transferring your settings to another
computer by copying this folder to the new computer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!